# Intermittent error when using mod_proxy to do reverse proxy to SOAP service

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I get this error every few minutes when using mod_proxy as a reverse proxy to a SOAP web service.  There's probably 3 or 4 requests going per seconds so we're talking around 1 or 2 out of every thousand that have this error.

```
[Tue Nov 23 11:44:14 2010] [error] [client 172.16.1.31] (20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server soap1.server:8888
[Tue Nov 23 11:44:14 2010] [error] [client 172.16.1.31] proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /someapp/path/to/web/service
```

This causes the request to fail.  If I have the client connect directly to the soap server without using the proxy, success is 100% so the problem appears to be in the proxy

The configuration looks like this.  The purpose is to switch to a backup server if the primary one is unavailable:

```
<Proxy balancer://apicluster>  
BalancerMember http://soap1.server:8888 lbset=0 
BalancerMember http://soap2.server:8888 lbset=1 
</Proxy>  

ProxyPass /someapp balancer://apicluster/someapp 
ProxyPassReverse / balancer://apicluster/someapp
```

Has anyone run into this and found a fix?  There's some mentions in bug reports but no solutions.  The only thing that may be unusual is the client request could be 100MB or larger, so the request could take a little longer than you'd expect for a SOAP call.

Comment: The answer by David Purdue (SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1) is a valid answer nowadays (2016).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this.  This is a bug in mod_proxy that can be avoided by putting these lines in your httpd.conf:

```
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
```

https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37770

For info on what these variables do see the [`mod_proxy` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html). They have a specific section, Protocol Adjustment, that addresses these variables.

Comment: Depending on your installation, the `httpd.conf` file might be in the following locations ([source](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/working_with_the_apache_config_file.html#the-location-of-the-apache-configuration-file)): - `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`
- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`
- `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`
- `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Answer (score 5):

Take note of the Apache documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_http.html

It seems there is a race condition in mod_proxy_http, but it can be avoided by including:

```
SetEnv proxy-initial-not-pooled 1
```

Which prevents Apache using a pooled connection if this is an initial request.

The document does note that this setting will give a performance downgrade.

Comment: `proxy-initial-not-pooled` is only effective if you have a specific patch, which I believe is not a part of httpd 2.2. I don't know about httpd 2.4. See https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=37770#c88

Answer (score 0):

You can also suppress this related error message (`AH01102: error reading status line from remote server`) by using the apache module mod_reqtimeout and this conf directive:

```
RequestReadTimeout header=30
```

You'll likely have to enable the reqtimeout module, as follows:

```
$ sudo a2enmod reqtimeout
$ sudo apache2ctl restart
```