# error 20014 with mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I have strange situation. I need to call a program in cgi-bin from within a perl script. When I try to do that with `exec($program)`, I get

```
(20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server
proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by ...
```

The long story... I am calling `mapserv` (http://mapserver.org) as a cgi program from `OpenLayers` (http://openlayers.org). Ordinarily, my web site is served by Perl Dancer, but the mapserver calls are made directly to `http://server/cgi-bin/mapserv` from JavaScript. The Dancer web site is served by `Starman` behind an Apache2 proxy front-end. This is how it looks

```
[browser] -> http://server/app -> [apache2] -> proxy port 5000 -> Starman
    |
    |
    +-> http://server/cgi-bin/mapserv -> [apache2] -> cgi-bin -> mapserv
```

This is what I am trying to accomplish

```
[browser] -> http://server/app -> [apache2] -> proxy port 5000 -> Starman
                                                                    |
                                                                    |
                               mapserv <-- cgi-bin <-- [apache2] <--+
```

I saw this question re: [20014 error](https://serverfault.com/questions/206738/intermittent-error-when-using-mod-proxy-to-do-reverse-proxy-to-soap-service), but that suggested solution didn't help.

Any other hints?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure which version of Apache are you using. I've had a similar issue with Apache 2.2.22, and Apache's documentation suggests the following:

> proxy-initial-not-pooled
>
> > If this variable is set no pooled connection will be reused if the client connection is an initial connection. This avoids the "proxy: error reading status line from remote server" error message caused by the race condition that the backend server closed the pooled connection after the connection check by the proxy and before data sent by the proxy reached the backend. It has to be kept in mind that setting this variable downgrades performance, especially with HTTP/1.0 clients.

But i'm not sure if that will resolve your issue.